# How to plot a gaussian distribution on a histogram with known ranges for bars in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram, distribution, gaussian

How can I plot the histogram for a set of data in which the beginning and end of each bar is known? Also, I want to plot a Gaussian distribution, whether it is for the aforementioned data set or any other one, over the histogram. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
% Sample Data
data = randn(100);

% Setup beginning and end of each bar
edges = -2:0.2:2;

% Show the histogram
histogram(data,edges)
```

Comment: I want to limit the range foe each bar and show it in the x-axis

Comment: @user2983136 could you give an example of what you would like to do and what you expect the output to look like for that example? It's not very clear from the question.